# Porting LKM to LSM - Unexpected behavior

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have a Linux Kernel Module that checks for the presence of a specific USB device and performs a printk upon a match.  This code works fine and performs as i expect.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/usb.h>
#include <linux/usb/hcd.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int HARD_VEND;
static int HARD_PROD;
static char *HARD_SERI;

struct USBCred
{
    int vendor;
    int product;
    char serial[128];
};

static struct USBCred create_creds_device(struct usb_device *dev)
{
    struct USBCred creds;

    creds.vendor = dev->descriptor.idVendor;
    creds.product = dev->descriptor.idProduct;

    if((dev->serial) == NULL)
    {
        strcpy(creds.serial, "(null)");
    } else {
        strcpy(creds.serial, dev->serial);
    }

    return creds;
}

static struct USBCred create_creds_hub(struct usb_bus *bus)
{
    struct USBCred creds;

    creds.vendor = bus->root_hub->descriptor.idVendor;
    creds.product = bus->root_hub->descriptor.idProduct;

    if((bus->root_hub->serial) == NULL)
    {
        strcpy(creds.serial, "(null)");
    } else {
        strcpy(creds.serial, bus->root_hub->serial);
    }

    return creds;
}


static int check_usb_creds(struct USBCred usb_data) 
{
    if(usb_data.vendor != HARD_VEND && usb_data.product != HARD_PROD && strcmp(usb_data.serial, HARD_SERI))
    {
        return 1;
    } else 
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "*********** RootPug Module - Match ***********");
        printk(KERN_INFO "Vendor ID = %x, HC Vendor ID  = %x", usb_data.vendor, HARD_VEND);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Product ID = %x, HC Product ID = %x", usb_data.product, HARD_PROD);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Serial = %s, HC Serial= %s", usb_data.serial, HARD_SERI);
        return 0; 
    }
}

static int __init usb_fun_init (void)  
{  
    int id;
    int chix;

    struct USBCred cred;

    struct usb_bus *bus; 
    struct usb_device *dev, *childdev = NULL;

    HARD_VEND = 0x26bd;
        HARD_PROD = 0x9917;
        HARD_SERI = "070172966462EB10";

    mutex_lock(&usb_bus_idr_lock);

    idr_for_each_entry(&usb_bus_idr, bus, id)
        {        
        cred = create_creds_hub(bus);
        //print_USBCred(cred);
        check_usb_creds(cred);

        dev = bus->root_hub;
        usb_hub_for_each_child(dev, chix, childdev)
        {
            if(childdev)
            {           
                usb_lock_device(childdev);
                cred = create_creds_device(childdev);
                //print_USBCred(cred);
                check_usb_creds(cred);
                usb_unlock_device(childdev);
                        }
        }
    }

    mutex_unlock(&usb_bus_idr_lock);    
    return 0;  
}

static void __exit usb_fun_exit (void)  
{  
    printk(KERN_INFO "***************** RootPug Module - Exit *****************\n");  
} 

module_init(usb_fun_init);
module_exit(usb_fun_exit);
```

[image: Working LKM]

When moving over to an LSM, the LSM registers without an issue, and the hook registers correctly, yet the code is not behaving as I would like, and I can not understand why. I have added debugging statements to understand at which points the code is getting to, but it seems the `idr_for_each_entry()` is not being executed, as the debug statment ithin that loop is not being printed. I have used a flag based system to provide a mechanism for having -EPERM as the default return value, being overwritten if the usb is found.

[image: KernelFail]

I cannot understand why only the mutex is being performed, with no check to the hubs or usb devices, yet the same code works as an LKM. The actual code that is in question is within the `appcl_inode_create` hook. I have left out the other hooks for brevity, but they currently do nothing except return the expected value of 0.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kd.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/tracehook.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/lsm_hooks.h>
#include <linux/xattr.h>
#include <linux/security.h>
#include <linux/capability.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/mman.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/pagemap.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/magic.h>
#include <linux/ctype.h>
#include <linux/swap.h>
#include <linux/spinlock.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/dcache.h>
#include <linux/file.h>
#include <linux/fdtable.h>
#include <linux/namei.h>
#include <linux/mount.h>
#include <linux/tty.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/atomic.h>
#include <linux/bitops.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/parser.h>
#include <linux/nfs_mount.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>
#include <linux/posix-timers.h>
#include <linux/syslog.h>
#include <linux/user_namespace.h>
#include <linux/export.h>
#include <linux/msg.h>
#include <linux/shm.h>
#include <linux/gfp.h>

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/cred.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/fs_struct.h>
#include <linux/fsnotify.h>
#include <linux/path.h>
#include <linux/fdtable.h>
#include <linux/binfmts.h>
#include <linux/time.h>

#include <linux/usb.h>
#include <linux/usb/hcd.h>

#include "include/appcl_lsm.h"
//#include "include/audit.h"

MODULE_LICENSE("GPLv3");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Jack Cuthbertson");


static int HARD_VEND;
static int HARD_PROD;
static char *HARD_SERI;

struct USBCred
{
    int vendor;
    int product;
    char serial[128];
};

static struct USBCred create_creds_device(struct usb_device *dev)
{
    struct USBCred creds;

    creds.vendor = dev->descriptor.idVendor;
    creds.product = dev->descriptor.idProduct;

    if((dev->serial) == NULL)
    {
        strcpy(creds.serial, "(null)");
    } else {
        strcpy(creds.serial, dev->serial);
    }

    return creds;
}

static struct USBCred create_creds_hub(struct usb_bus *bus)
{
    struct USBCred creds;

    creds.vendor = bus->root_hub->descriptor.idVendor;
    creds.product = bus->root_hub->descriptor.idProduct;

    if((bus->root_hub->serial) == NULL)
    {
        strcpy(creds.serial, "(null)");
    } else {
        strcpy(creds.serial, bus->root_hub->serial);
    }

    return creds;
}


static int check_usb_creds(struct USBCred usb_data) 
{
    if(usb_data.vendor != HARD_VEND && usb_data.product != HARD_PROD && strcmp(usb_data.serial, HARD_SERI))
    {
            printk(KERN_INFO "*********** RootPlug Module - Non Match ***********");
            printk(KERN_INFO "Vendor ID = %x, HC Vendor ID  = %x", usb_data.vendor, HARD_VEND);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Product ID = %x, HC Product ID = %x", usb_data.product, HARD_PROD);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Serial = %s, HC Serial= %s", usb_data.serial, HARD_SERI);
        return 1;
    } else 
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "*********** RootPlug Module - Match ***********");
        printk(KERN_INFO "Vendor ID = %x, HC Vendor ID  = %x", usb_data.vendor, HARD_VEND);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Product ID = %x, HC Product ID = %x", usb_data.product, HARD_PROD);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Serial = %s, HC Serial= %s", usb_data.serial, HARD_SERI);
        return 0; 
    }
}

static int appcl_lsm_inode_create(struct inode *dir, struct dentry *dentry, umode_t mode)
{
int id;
int chix;

int flag = -EPERM;

struct USBCred cred;

struct usb_bus *bus; 
struct usb_device *dev, *childdev = NULL;

    HARD_VEND = 0x26bd;
    HARD_PROD = 0x9917;
    HARD_SERI = "070172966462EB10";

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Rootplug: Beginning check\n");

    mutex_lock(&usb_bus_idr_lock);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Rootplug: Mutex locked the bus list\n");

    //loop though all usb buses
    idr_for_each_entry(&usb_bus_idr, bus, id)
    {        
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Rootplug: Checking hubs.\n");        
        cred = create_creds_hub(bus);

        //Check creds of usb buses
        if(check_usb_creds(cred) == 0)
        {
            mutex_unlock(&usb_bus_idr_lock);
            printk(KERN_ALERT "Rootplug: Unlock hub success!\n");
            flag = 0;
        } else {
            printk(KERN_ALERT "Rootplug: Unlock hub fail!\n");
        }


        dev = bus->root_hub;
        usb_hub_for_each_child(dev, chix, childdev)
        {
            if(childdev)
            {   
                printk(KERN_ALERT "Rootplug: Checking USB devices\n");      
                usb_lock_device(childdev);
                cred = create_creds_device(childdev);

                if(check_usb_creds(cred) == 0)
                {
                    usb_unlock_device(childdev);
                    mutex_unlock(&usb_bus_idr_lock);
                    printk(KERN_ALERT "Rootplug: Unlock USB success!\n");       
                } else {
                    usb_unlock_device(childdev);
            printk(KERN_ALERT "Rootplug: Unlock USB Failure!\n");       
                }

            } else {

                printk(KERN_ALERT "Rootplug: No child dev\n");
            }
        }
    }

    mutex_unlock(&usb_bus_idr_lock);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Rootplug: Unlock failed - Flag: %i\n", flag);
    return flag;
}

static struct security_hook_list appcl_hooks[] = {
    /*
     * XATTR HOOKS
     */
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_setxattr, appcl_lsm_inode_setxattr),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_post_setxattr, appcl_lsm_inode_post_setxattr),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_getxattr, appcl_lsm_inode_getxattr),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_removexattr, appcl_lsm_inode_removexattr),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(d_instantiate, appcl_lsm_d_instantiate),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_setsecurity, appcl_lsm_inode_setsecurity),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_init_security, appcl_lsm_inode_init_security),
    /*
     * INODE HOOKS
     */
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_alloc_security, appcl_lsm_inode_alloc_security),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_free_security, appcl_lsm_inode_free_security),
    /*
     * General permission mask
     */
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_permission, appcl_lsm_inode_permission),
    /*
     * Specific permission hooks
     */
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_create, appcl_lsm_inode_create),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_rename, appcl_lsm_inode_rename),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_link, appcl_lsm_inode_link),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_unlink, appcl_lsm_inode_unlink),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_symlink, appcl_lsm_inode_symlink),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_mkdir, appcl_lsm_inode_mkdir),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_rmdir, appcl_lsm_inode_rmdir),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_mknod, appcl_lsm_inode_mknod),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_readlink, appcl_lsm_inode_readlink),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_follow_link, appcl_lsm_inode_follow_link),
    //LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_setattr, appcl_lsm_inode_setattr),
    //LSM_HOOK_INIT(inode_getattr, appcl_lsm_inode_getattr),
    /*
     * FILE HOOKS
     */
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(file_alloc_security, appcl_lsm_file_alloc_security),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(file_free_security, appcl_lsm_file_free_security),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(file_permission, appcl_lsm_file_permission),
    //LSM_HOOK_INIT(file_fcntl, appcl_lsm_file_fcntl),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(file_open, appcl_lsm_file_open),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(file_receive, appcl_lsm_file_receive),
    /*
     * CRED HOOKS
     */
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(cred_alloc_blank, appcl_lsm_cred_alloc_blank),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(cred_free, appcl_lsm_cred_free),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(cred_prepare, appcl_lsm_cred_prepare),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(cred_transfer, appcl_lsm_cred_transfer),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(bprm_set_creds, appcl_lsm_bprm_set_creds),
    /*
     * SUPERBLOCK HOOKS
     */
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(sb_alloc_security, appcl_lsm_sb_alloc_security),
    LSM_HOOK_INIT(sb_free_security, appcl_lsm_sb_free_security),
};

static __init int appcl_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Rootplug: Module loading... \n");

    /*
     * Set security attributes for initial task
     */

    security_add_hooks(appcl_hooks, ARRAY_SIZE(appcl_hooks), "appcl");

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Rootplug: module initialised\n");

    return 0;
}

DEFINE_LSM(appcl) = {
        .name = "appcl",
        .init = appcl_init,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that handled the matching used a different alert level for the printk function. As such, the messages were not displayed to the console at that stage in the boot process.

What was:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "message");
```

Should be:

```
printk(KERN_ALERT "message");
```

The matching function was being called, after recompiling the kernel with the hooks forced to return 0, i could see from `/var/log/*` that the function was being executed and outputting the correct information.